# Where is episode S16E13 of Power Rangers Jungle Fury filmed?

Tags: film-location, power-rangers

In the *Power Rangers Jungle Fury* episode "Ghost of a Chance" (S16E13), the rangers travel to the spirit world to train with fallen masters.  The setting for the spirit world is very beautiful, and real.  The entire forest grove is covered with magenta plants of some sort.

Based on the rest of the show, I don't think they would have flown to Latvia or someplace to film - this was not Game of Thrones.  This must be North America.  But it is atypical for this show or any of the Power Rangers franchise to choose a location based on natural beauty.

I want to know more about this place.  Can anyone figure out where it is?

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer for anything like this is… Canada, quite often British Columbia.
It's cheap for US shows to film there, there is a lot of woodland, usually coniferous as we see in this scene.

[IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1121628/locations?ref_=tt_dt_dt), however, says Auckland, New Zealand and Japan.
I'm going to stick my neck out here and say, New Zealand doesn't have that type of conifer - though I am by no means any kind of horticulturalist. It would also seem that the NZ government really doesn't want this type of forest being allowed free reign and have a [scheme to reduce them](https://www.doc.govt.nz/nature/pests-and-threats/weeds/common-weeds/wilding-conifers/)
There's no way that it's Japan either. Japan simply does not look like that, for similar reasons to NZ.
I could almost have been swayed into thinking it was out the back of Pinewood, but that's just not as hilly and looks like a much more managed forest, in avenues. Canada has a lot of managed forest but it's so big that there's enough unmanaged to be easy to find some for filming.

So I'm back to… Canada.

A few days' advance prep by [greens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greensman) and the [art department](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_department) and you have an odd overlay of what looks like dried, pink-dyed ferns and grasses that someone is going to have to clean up afterwards.

Canada has been doing this for so long it's become a bit of a meme…

[image]